Authentication with a service account to an API runing in Google Cloud Run in Python
I'm trying to connect to a Fast API (running in Google Cloud Run) from outside the Google Cloud Project. For this I have created a Service Account with the role Cloud Run Invoker (using IAM).
Now I'm trying to make a REST call to the API.
I got it working somehow. But I'm not satisfied with the solution.
Is there a way I can  avoid the gcloud command and do the whole thing in python without default login?
I want to avoid setting the service account credential with gcloud and accessing it with default login, because the API will be used by others and it should be minimal affort to get started with. Installing and set up of gcloud isn't.
Any kind of hints  would be appreciated.
I downloaded the service account credential info file (key.json).
I activate the service account with the command:

gcloud auth activate-service-account caller-sa@api_proj.iam.gserviceaccount.com --key-file=./key.json --project=api_proj

Then I used the following code:
import google.auth
import google.auth.transport.requests
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
import google.oauth2.id_token
import requests
import google.oauth2.credentials

service_account_file = "./key.json"

credentials, project_id = google.auth.default()

request = Request()
credentials.refresh(request)
id_token = credentials.id_token

headers = {"Authorization": f"Bearer {id_token}"}

url = "https://api-proj.europe-west3.run.app/predict"
data = """ Mi chiamo Pietro. Sono di Roma."""
response = requests.post(url=url, headers=headers, json={"data": data})
response.raise_for_status()
print(response.json())


A good question.
See Authenticating users.
You're correct to be concerned about the requirement of using gcloud and Service Accounts in this case:

using gcloud is a good approach when you know that your users (e.g. organizational users) have gcloud.
Service Accounts should be used when you have a non-human user (e.g. some software) that operates independently. You never want to be distributing Service Account keys.

There are 2 main solutions with human users:

You can user your Google Cloud Project's (IAM) users but this requires you to know these users in advance, add them to your project etc. This approach is best used for internal users within an organization.
For "customers" and situations with some form of open-ended user base and users who may follow some user-driven or you-drive sign-up process, Google provides the solutions outlined in the link above: Google Identity or Firebase Auth. Under these approaches, you can supported federated identities (Google, Microsoft, Facebook, Apple etc.), retain the controls you need to limit who can access your solution but at the expense of addition work (as outlined in the link).

Using this approach, Google Identity or Firebase Auth will generate identity tokens for authenticated (and possibly authorized) users who will then be permitted to invoke your (Cloud Run) FastAPI service.
